# JavaScript & .htaccess rules are clashing

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

Few weeks ago I have asked on here how to detecting the current page and add class of .active. I have received the following working solution using JavaScript: You can view the question here: [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470144/detecting-the-current-page-and-add-class-of-active-it-is-working-but).

```
$("#mainMenu a").filter(function () {
  var _href = location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
  if (location.pathname === "/") {
     // change http://example.com/ to http://example.com/index.php
     _href += "index.php";
  }
  return _href === this.href;
}).addClass("active");
```

**However**, I now wanted to remove the .php extensions from the URL's and I did that using the following .httacess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
ErrorDocument 404 /404 
ErrorDocument 504 /504 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

# remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops 
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP 
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L] 

# remove index 
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately 
# The trailing slash is removed in a next request, so be efficient and 
# dont put it on there at all 
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1 [R=301,L] 

# remove slash if not directory 
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ 
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301,L] 

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect 
# On some hosts RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f will be true, even if 
# no such file exists. Be safe and add an extra condition 
# There is no point in escaping a dot in a string 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|\.php)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

The problem is, when I added the .httacess file above, the JavaScript stopped working... Why is that?
Is there a more efficient way of doing this using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

It seem like I have fixed it, but I don't know if this solution is good, any advices please? 
I have changed the href from index.php to /index and it works...

```
<li><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
```